# I have a problem with a sequence of code in second Activity

Tags: android

I have a problem with this code sequence.
If I comment all the content from "onCreate" , opens me in Quiz Activity but it does not show me anything from my database.
If i uncomment code sequence , the application is being blocked

```
Toolbar toolbar2;
RecyclerView recycler_category;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz);



    toolbar2=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    toolbar2.setTitle("Quiz");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);

    recycler_category=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
    recycler_category.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_category.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));

    CategoryAdapter adapter=new CategoryAdapter(Quiz.this, DBHelper.getInstance(this).getAllCategories());
    int spaceInPizel=4;
    recycler_category.addItemDecoration(new SpaceDecoration(spaceInPizel));
    recycler_category.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this ' If i uncomment code sequence , the application is being blocked'

Comment: crash :)) , the end ,over , the application stops

Comment: can you please post your crash logs?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CgAX1wM.png

Comment: you just comment one line ' setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);' and run your project and let me know the result

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TZXER3U.png - great , thanks , but now i have this errors

Comment: if my answer helped you please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: To read code from image is really hard. Please post the code/crash logs rather image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you must be using below code (something similar) in your style file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

In your style you are already mentioning for Action bar and via your code you are also adding toolbar as mentioned below in your code.

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);
```

This is the problem. Either remove ** setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);** method or change theme. Use theme with NoActionBar